# iOS pdf encryption 256-bit AES

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, encryption

I'm using these codes to encrypt my pdf files in iOS:

```
CFDictionarySetValue(myDictionary, kCGPDFContextUserPassword, CFSTR("userpassword"));
CFDictionarySetValue(myDictionary, kCGPDFContextOwnerPassword, CFSTR("ownerpassword"));
```

When I check the encryption level it's:

> "Acrobat 7.0 and later"

Which means it's a 128-bit AES.

I'm a little paranoid, and I would like to have a 256-bit AES encryption ("Acrobat X and later  Encryption Level: 256-bit AES")

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Hi there, have you found a way to use 256-bit AES encryption instead of 128?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither AES 128 or 256 can be brute forced, there is no added advantage to 256.

See [How secure is AES 128](https://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1279619): "even with a supercomputer, it would take 1 billion billion years to crack the 128-bit AES key using brute force attack."

The thing to be paranoid about is  "userpassword" and "ownerpassword". Brute force attacks are generally based on lists of frequent passwords, see Password lists at [SecLists](https://github.com/danielmiessler/SecLists/tree/master/Passwords).

[Passmaker](http://passmaker.com) is a good start for secure passwords.

Comment: Thanks @zaph AES 128 is immensely secure, makes me question the existence of AES 256. I'll accept your advise to use a stronger password. One more thing, I'm just curious is it the limitation of iOS to use AES 256?

Comment: iOS Common Crypto supports all three AES key sizes, 128, 192 & 256 bits. One reason for the key sizes is that the US Government had a requirement for three key sizes. It is also a hedge against the future. These days there is small performance difference between the key sizes, originally there was more, AES was adopted in NIST in 2000. Since there is generally no longer a performance penalty AES 256 is being used by default.

Comment: Thanks. Tried to use CFDictionarySetValue(myDictionary, kCGPDFContextEncryptionKeyLength, (__bridge const void *)([NSNumber numberWithInt:40])); //test 128 and set it to 256 but it returns an empty pdf since it's only able to support from 40 to 128.